# Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true) = Warning

Tags: swiftui

struct Map_Finder: View {
@StateObject private var viewModel = Map_FinderModel()

```
var body: some View {
    `This where Im getting the warning' Map(coordinateRegion: $viewModel.region, showsUserLocation: true)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .accentColor(Color(.systemPink))
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.checkIfLocationServicesIsEnabled()
        }
}
```

}

#Preview {
Map_Finder()

`Whenever I run the builder I sit at a white screen`

Comment: Read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
 show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can compile and run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Try removing the view model, thats what the `View` struct hierarchy and state/binding is for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm getting a warning within my code. The line of code is:               Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true)                                                 The warning states: "'init(coordinateRegion:interactionModes:showsUserLocation:userTrackingMode:)' was deprecated in iOS 17.0: Use Map initializers that take a MapContentBuilder instead."  I'm not sure how to move forward.